# Location on Android

Tags: android, android-location

I am developing an Android app where I am going to use Android locations. I know that are 2 ways to do that(GPS and network provider). I have read a lot about this topic but I still have some doubts. Suppose that I am a director in some company and I want to know where my workers every time I want. Could you tell me which period of update is the best time to put in UpdateLocation?  I know that the best is when I put 0 for seconds and 0 for metres but that is really bad for battery. But I want to save battery as much as possible.
What are your advices?

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: Try some values and measure on a few common devices until you get something that's acceptable for you.

Comment: Thanks mate.Could you tell me what is your opinion?

Comment: It is better to send sms request to obtain current location of your worker.  But it is costly and saves battery

Comment: Just one more question....What do you think about Android Location Fused Provider? Is that a replacement for GPS and Network provider or what?

Comment: @Atenica you can use Gps and Network providers but Fused Location Api  doing same work with less energy consumption and much more faster. In this site you can see battery drains : http://blog.lemberg.co.uk/fused-location-provider

Comment: So, If I understand correctly, I could use just Fused Location API without Nework provider and GPS?  It hase the same function like these two?

Answer (score 1):

In you case using periodic location updates seems like not very good solution. If running all the time, Gps drain battery (Network provider a bit less). Your employees will not appreciate such app. 
You may want to use geofencing instead. It is specifically created for low power consumption application. 
Here is algorithm I used in one project- when you want to start monitoring, get current user location, create circle with some radius (perhaps 100 meters outdoors). Whenever person walk our of this circle, get new current location, save it to db for a history, remove old geofence and create anew.
Here is my code for using geofences in background Service (even when app is closed). just modify it a bit.
https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B3nZIRmN7uQyazVzMzNDTXA0Q0k&usp=sharing

Comment: Good approach, for example you can separate a garden to piece of circle zones.  like zone A, zone B, zone C.  Then you can monitoring them like  a worker is in zone A.

Answer (score 0):

Use this variables :-

```
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 2;
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

On documentation google suggests for realtime applications, 5 seconds interval and HIGH_ACCURACY. So 5 seconds interval is best for you too.

**I never suggest requesting** location updates with aggressively parameters like 0 interval. Because, AFAIK, when you get a LocationManager instance, it's related to whole android system, so it could give bad results to main thread (I've also tried passing a looper but even in that case, animations aren't smooth in my app)

**I suggest absolutely** fused location provider. Because it wraps gps and network providers, also uses sensors on your device. For example device won't deal with getting location when you not moving.

**Battery :** Honestly, With above approach battery will be drained too fast.

A good example for you from commonsware : [link](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-locpoll)

Read this project, in it you'll see nice tactics about power management, wakeup, location updates and timeout. But it uses LocationManager. If you combine with instead Fused location api, it could be better.

Comment: So, it is the best to use Fused Location Provider? Is that the replacement for gps and local network provider or what? I have read about that, but it would be cool to hear your opinion...

Comment: I suggest using fused provider. You can watch this video [link](https://youtu.be/Bte_GHuxUGc?t=735) from 12:15 to 14:45 It shows, simply, how cool the fused provider and its' benefits.

Comment: Also check  [this repository](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/tree/master/LocationUpdates) to learn how to use fused provider api

Comment: Thanks mate, I will try this Fused provider, and I hope that will give good results   :)

Comment: Hey friend just one more question for you :) When you said that with "this" approach battery will be drained too fast did You mean on Fused Location Provider or on something else? Because I have watched on Youtube vide from that you have sent me and there they said that Fused provider doesn't consumes battery too fast. :)

Comment: Yes, but more accurate locations mean more power usage. If you use balanced power option for priority, uses less battery but doesn't give more accurate results. BTW probably this will work in a service and background. To keep working whole tracking process, you'll need device stay awake. And there are few conditions about this process. If you pay attention commonware's repository (link above in my post) , will give you better understanding of what I mention.

Comment: Well I will have a background and that background will send me request to the android device to obtain location, so is there some way to obtain location with Fused Location just on demand? Could I set high-accuracy priority when location request is obtained on demand? I don't know if you understand me, and thank's a lot for helping me :)

Comment: You mean, at some time you wanna check device's location instead of the device sending to server periodically ?